How do I calculate how long my backup power/AC Power supply will last?
How do I calculate how long my backup power supply or power bank will run an appliance?

Time = energy / power
Where Energy is the amount of energy in the power bank and power is the average power that the load takes.
For example, if a fully-charged power bank stores 500 Watt-hour of energy and the load uses 50 Watt of power on average, the power bank can power that load for 10 hours.
Now you will ask: "How much power does my load use?". Answer: we have no way of knowing, and you probably don't have a way to measure it.
Therefore, the most practical way to know how long a power bank can power a load is empirical: try and see.
